# Is it possible to register new class into another class in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, structuremap

Is this possible in Visual studio 2010?...
I have a structuremap registry class:

```
public class RepositoryRegisters: IRegistry
{
    public RepositoryRegisters()
    {
         For<IUserRepository>().Use<UserRepository>();
         For<IGroupRepository>().Use<GroupRepository>();
    }
}
```

now if I add new class that implements `IRepository<T>`

I want it automatically added to the constructor of the above class (`RepositoryRegisters`).
So if I add ie. MyRepository class, that visual studio automatically adds this line into the RepositoryRegisters constructor:

```
For<IMyRepository>().Use<MyRepository>();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [scan with DefaultConvention](http://abstractcode.com/abstractblog/archive/2010/07/03/structuremap-part-4-scanning.aspx) you don't need to add anything else to the Registry as long as you follow the same naming convention.

```
  Scan(scanner =>
    {
      scanner.AssemblyContainingType<IRepository<>>();
      scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
    });
```

This will connect all implementations to an interface by name (IUserRepository -> UserRepository, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll require [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) eventually.

edit: you could also try some [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) magic.

Comment: Ok but with ioc and reflection this is possible only in runtime., I want this to be done in design time.

Comment: I want something like this: User right-clicks on a folder in visual studio project, he chooses Add new Item and selects my custom class item from the list. Then when the class is inserted in the solution folder, the visual studio automatically opens the RepositoryRegisters.cs file, finds its constructor, and add a line of code.